# How do I set different application icon for different configurations?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

In the project properties dialog, on the 'Application' tab, the dropdown for choosing the configuration is disabled; how can I set the icon to be dependent on the build configuration?

Comment: Is this actually possible?  I thought this only changed the way the code was compiled - i.e. Release build would take out debug symbols etc.

Comment: I'm not sure..you can certainly change more than just debug symbols in/out, but whether this is available or not, and whether it is easily available or needs a custom build script, I'm unsure.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in visual studio but you can probably do it with a pre-build event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might shed some light - but I think it's only for VS2010:

[application-icon--how-to-select-different-icon-based-on-compiler-directives-32338](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/application-icon--how-to-select-different-icon-based-on-compiler-directives-32338.shtml)

Comment: Hmm unfortunately not available in VS 2008 (at least, not in VB Express edition)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would change the configuration but remember to change the Icon manually in the Project Properties before compiling for each configuration.

Comment: The manual step would require a manual test in our processes to ensure we don't deliver with the wrong icon...too error-prone for my liking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in my game.rc file:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//

...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

#if defined(RELEASECHANNEL_DEV)
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "game_dev.ico"
#else
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "game.ico"
#endif
```

I believe this file is initially generated for the project, but doesn't seem to be modified again. We use premake to create our VS project and use `resincludedirs( { "../resources" } )` to include the directory containing game.rc and game.ico.