# Manage multiple target projects under Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have written a Visual Studio C# project and I have the need to create two executable, one for a "lite version" and one for a "full version" of the same project.

The "lite version" will be a stripped down version of the full one so I want to share everything (code, resources, etc.) and, if possible, use compiling directive to isolate code blocks.

Can you tell me a way to do this in a clean way?

Comment: I suggest you think of other ways to do this.  It would take very little effort to decompile your code to avoid your compile directives. Just a fair warning before you go to the hasle of actually trying to do this.

Comment: To be honest, with a compile directive I want the compiler not to compile some lines or files so there is no way to discover "the full code" because "the full code" is part only of the "full version" binary (distributed elsewhere).

Comment: Even if do implement BigYellowCactus's solution the code will still be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new [Conditional compilation symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your project (say `FULLVERSION`). Create a [new Solution configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/307yt086%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (say ReleaseFullversion) using the [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and in this configuration, define the `FULLVERSION` constant.

---

You can then wrap code block with

```
#if FULLVERSION
 ...
#end if
```

or use the [Conditional atrribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
[Conditional("FULLVERSION")]
void MyMethod()
{...}
```

to create a stripped down version your application.

Code within these `#if`-blocks and these `Conditional` attributes won't be compiled into your assembly if the `FULLVERSION` constant is not set (the `Conditional` attributes just removes the call to that code block, actually).

---

Then you would either build a lite version of your solution, or a Fullversion, which includes the full code.

Comment: This looks the best solution but I see a little problem: how can I conditionally change the binary name, icon, description, etc. in this way?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893003/change-assembly-name-based-on-configuration-visual-studio-2005-2008)

Comment: Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208084/how-to-use-a-different-assembly-name-for-different-configurations)

Comment: For icons, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612363/how-do-i-set-different-application-icon-for-different-configurations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio [Post Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) events, where from the batch call `DEVENV.EXE` to your project with some special parameter that makes it compile in a different way.

[DevEnv explanation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevEnvcomSairamasTipOfTheDay.aspx)

[Using Devenv at the command prompt to build projects](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/20/using-devenv-at-the-command-prompt-to-build-projects/)

Answer (score 1):

To do this all within visual studio, you require something of a strange ritual that is a little non-obvious to anyone simply looking at your project, so it is important to figure out a training regimen to make sure everyone knows what is going on.

First, right-click on the solution you have and go to properties.  Click on "Configuration Manager" and make a new configuration.  Call it "Lite" or whatever pleases you.

You may then right-click each project in your solution to set the conditional compilation properties you need.  You may then use [Conditional Compilation Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to isolate what is 'full' and what is 'lite'.

After this has been fully configured, it will appear in the top of visual studio's UI - where you normally see Debug and Release, you will now see Lite or whatever you just configured.